# Adding .htaccess to disallow sites/default/files directory from any access

Tags: ubercart

Customers at my site upload private files using node checkout module which finally land in sites/default/files directory as part of their order. 
Unfortunately I could never find a way till now to restrict those files to the owners only. I've even used User File module, but this module stopped my site.

Customer can upload files as their product order even as anonymous but to checkout they will need to login.

**So if I add .htaccess in this directory disallowing everybody in the world read access, will this idea work?**

I was thinking to write a hook so that as soon as a product is checked out, it's associated uploaded file can be moved to some private location, or have it's read permission removed( as hosting is on linux).
**Any ideas?**

I'm using Drupal-6